# How should i deploy all my APIs?

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I'm fairly new to AWS and before i realised how awesome it is, the cost of running an ec2 instances hit me to reality.

So here's my problem-

I have about 130 apis(Spring boot) to run my application. And as of yet, I've build them into about 15 modules. For example - settings module has all the apis related to changing the username, the password.

And then i uploaded these modules through Elastic Beanstalk into about 5 application - each consisting of 3 environments.

Now I get this feeling that i'm doing it all wrong, cause the cost spikes upto 300$ a month.
Since i'm from India, here amazon doesnt support reserved instances.

It'd be a great help if you could guide me through on what should be done instead.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly hard to give any solution without understanding your requirements ex: peak load, dependencies of these applications, etc.

Just based on preliminary info you can try to use Amazon ECS/Docker so that you can deploy multiple applications on single host.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Amazon's [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) service.

> WS Lambda lets you run code without provisioning or managing servers. You pay only for the compute time you consume - there is no charge when your code is not running. With Lambda, you can run code for virtually any type of application or backend service - all with zero administration.